# PHP - API file returning junk HTML instead of JSON response when hosted online

Tags: php, json

I have created API services using PHP and it works fine on my local(xampp)

However, when I host the files online, it return junk HTML instead of JSON response. The response I receive is something similar to this:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
<script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
  <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("6f52ec93eff14fb17fe0ff4703436db4");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";location.href="http://example.com/?ckattempt=1";
  </script>
  <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
</body>
```

Can someone please advise what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the website hasn't been hacked? - This looks like some obfuscated code.

Comment: I am using Free web hosting platform. I am thinking this shouldn't be the case

Comment: Check the php is still correct, and check server logs

Comment: Thought the same thing. It's not really obfuscated code, though. It only places a cookie, using the result of a slowAES.decrypt. Distributed AES cracking :p?? Weird!

Comment: Found the code in an github gist: https://gist.github.com/Schm1tz1/31a14ba2a83b5ac21cd7 No explanation was added there, though, and the redirect and used numbers differ.

Comment: "Update: The problem seems to be caused by some HTML and JavaScript code which is automatically added by the free hosting service I am using (byethost)" - it's possible your hosting. I found slowAES mentioned as counter-ddos measure hostings could use (extra barrier for bots), maybe that's what they did? In any case, I don't believe your own code magically spawns this javascript...

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason might be you have disabled browser cookies or disabled javascript. Since free hosting services required to set a cookie for better services in (my case byethost) and cookies required javascript to be enabled. So it has nothing to do with code but with the hosting server, you are using.